# Is there a way to downgrade Ubuntu without losing any files?

Tags: 13.10, downgrade

I want to downgrade ubuntu 13.10 to ubuntu 12.04 LTS without losing the installed apps and my files in the ubuntu folders.

Comment: Could you explain why? Why would you want to downgrade the entire OS? Ubuntu is not a monolothic entity like Windows and you might be able to downgrade specific programs if that's what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Downgrading is very tricky and it is very un-recommended. However if you insist, you can follow the guide from Ubuntu community page:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DowngradeHowto